# Displaying the post count of all custom taxonomy terms in a list format

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, api

I thought this would have displayed the post counts right next to the clickable links

```
wp_tag_cloud( 
array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 
'format' => 'list', 
'smallest' => 12,  
'largest' => 12, 
'number' => 10000 , 
'separator' => '<li>' ,  
'topic_count_text_callback'=> 'default_topic_count_text' ) 
 );
```

but, it ends up displaying this;

```
item 1 
item 2 
item 3
```

What's the trick to make it display something like this?

```
item 1 (100)
item 2 ( 90 )
item 3 (15 )
```

I tried the following codex code, but that caused no visible change.

```
wp_tag_cloud( array( 'topic_count_text_callback' => 'my_tag_text_callback' ) ); 

function my_tag_text_callback( $count ) {
 return sprintf( _n('%s picture', '%s pictures', $count), number_format_i18n( $count ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function to build your own list if you want the count in there.

If we read the details of `topic_count_text_callback` we can see why it may *appear* to not be working:

> topic_count_text_callback
>
> (string) (optional) The function, which, given the count of the posts with that tag, returns a text for the **tooltip** of the tag link.
>   Default: default_topic_count_text

this function sets the link's `title` attribute text, it doesn't show the count with the term directly in the text. If you hover over the links you'll see the text pop-up in a tooltip next to your cursor.

Comment: Milo, I checked the wp_tag_cloud's output. In the title attribute of the outputted html, I see the count! Ex:  title='8 topics' Can something be done with that info without invoking another function?

Comment: http://dmblog.ca/2011/09/wordpress-tag-cloud-with-post-counts/

Answer (score 0):

```
$tax_list = wp_list_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'YOUR-CUSTOM-TAXONOMY', 'orderby' => 'name', 'show_count' => 1, 'pad_counts' => 0, 'hierarchical' => 1, 'echo' => 0 ) );
```

Echo $tax_list that to the browser and you're done.

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late. You can use `"show_count" => 1` as args in `wp_tag_cloud` and you will see your term count against its name. :-) Enjoy